# What way of dividing Tehilim by day of the week did Rabbi Menachem ben Zerah suggest?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

What way of dividing Tehilim by day of the week did Rabbi Menachem ben Zerach suggest?

In a similar question, a source was given, but I don't understand anything there.

Comment: Which similar question? Can you at least provide a link?

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39362&st=&pgnum=263

Comment: @Joel K Could you translate? I don't know Hebrew, or rather I can't understand Rashi script.

Comment: Is that the most recent printing available on Hebrew books

Answer (score 1):

This appears in [*Tzedah LaDerech, Ma'amar Revi'i, Kelal Chamishi*](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39362&st=&pgnum=263).

The suggested split is:

- Sunday: 1 - 31
- Monday: 32 - 50
- Tuesday: 51 - 72
- Wednesday: 73 - 89
- Thursday: 90 - 107
- Friday: 108 - 119
- Shabbat: 120 - 150